# Pullback induces isomorphism on the fibers

Tags: algebraic-topology, pullback

Suppose we are given a pullback diagram of topological spaces
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B\\
@VVV @VVV\\
C @>>>D
\end{CD}
and we want to look at the fibres of the maps $A\to C$ and $B\to D$. Then I know that the induced maps in the fibres are an isomorphism for each basepoint.

However, I fail to see why this is true.
Can someone elaborate on this??

Comment: Pullbacks compose and have the cancellation property…

Comment: @PrudiiArca I think I do not get what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiber of $A \rightarrow C$ at a point $c$ is given by the pullback
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
F & \rightarrow & A\\
\downarrow && \downarrow\\
* & \rightarrow & C
\end{array}$$

By pasting this square to the left of your square and using that pullbacks compose we find that the composite square is (isomorphic to) the fiber of $B \rightarrow D$ at $f(c)$.

Similarly, for a point $d$ *in the image of $f$*, we can compute the fiber by considering the pullback square
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
E & \rightarrow & \rightarrow & \rightarrow & B\\
\downarrow &&&& \downarrow\\
* &\rightarrow & C & \rightarrow & D
\end{array}$$
By using the universal property of your pullback square, the upper map factors via $A$ and we get two squares pasted together, the right one and composite one being pullbacks. Hence the left square is a pullback by the cancellation property, showing that the fiber of $B \rightarrow D$ at $d$ is isomorphic to the fiber of $A \rightarrow C$ for any $c$ with $f(c)=d$.